# Creating fixed length slices from slice

Tags: go

I have a slice of integers which I need to cut into smaller slices and use these new slices to a function call. I have to put 5 objects into every new slice. I could implement a solution which works correctly if the length of the `arr1` is dividable with `5`. However in other cases I will get an out of range error like this: `panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range [:26] with capacity 24`. I understand the problem and its cause, I give wrong index values at the last loop, my logic fails when `arr1_len` can't be divided by 5. My question is that how could I slice `arr1` into new slices with 5 objects in every slice, except the last one which can hold less than 5.? [Playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/OicmQthRW_X)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func printRes(l []int) {
    fmt.Println(l)
}

func sliceTest() {
    arr1 := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23}
    arr1_len := len(arr1)
    val := 5
    val2 := 0
    for i := 0; i <= arr1_len; i = i + val {
        val2 = i + val
        currentSlice := arr1[i:val2]
        fmt.Println(i, val2, currentSlice)
        printRes(currentSlice)
    }
}

func main() {
    sliceTest()
}
```

Comment: Take `if` and compare `val2` with the length of `arr1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check bounds:

```
val2 = i + val
if val2 >= len(arr1) {
    val2 = len(arr1)
}
```